# How to run a local docker image in a local OKD Cluster?

Tags: docker, openshift, okd

I have a local OKD cluster running on my dev machine (launched from `oc cluster up`). I have a local docker image named `local/app:latest`

How can I run that image in my local cluster?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this awesome youtube video, I was able to successfully deploy my local docker image onto the dedicated openshift platform's docker registry with the help of this: [Push local docker images to openshift registry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5VzXvvkiL4)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to push that image to OpenShift's built-in container [registry](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/registry/accessing-the-registry.html) and create a [Deployment](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/applications/deployments/what-deployments-are.html) object that references the [ImageStream](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/openshift_images/images-understand.html) object that gets created.

You could also configure your Deployment object to reference that image on an external publicly available container registry and use an [image-pull secret](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/openshift_images/managing_images/using-image-pull-secrets.html) to pull it.

Comment: There isn't a way to refer to my local image directly without publishing it to a registry?